# SCP file transfer not working in GitLab-CI

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, scp, gitlab-ci.yml

I am building a CICD pipeline using GitLab-CI.

The final stage of my pipeline transfers files from the build server (where the gitlab-runner.exe is installed) to the dev server. (Both build and dev servers are Windows Server 2019, by the way).

The gitlab-runner.exe uses the PowerShell executor, so each job is just a series of PowerShell commands to be run from the build server.

All the jobs work fine, except for the file transfer, which is a simple job like this:

```
transfer_job
    stage: transfer
    script:
        - scp C:\folder-to-copy\ admin@ipv4-of-dev-server:C:\destination
```

I've set up OpenSSH Client and Server on the build and dev server respectively, and set up key-based authentication between them.

Manually, I can SCP and SSH from the build server to the dev server just fine and without password authentication required.

But when a simple SCP command in the job above is run by the gitlab-runner.exe in a pipeline, it just doesn't complete. The pipeline does not fail, it just remains on that job until timeout (1hr).

I even tried putting the scp command into a powershell script located on the build server, and changing the job so that it just runs the script as below:

```
transfer_job
    stage: transfer
    script:
        - C:\scripts\transfer-script.ps1
```

This also fails, with the same problem. Timeout.

All I need is a reliable way to transfer files from server to server within a reasonable amount of time.

Any help would be extremely valuable.

Comment: NOTE: I do not necessarily need to use SCP for the file transfer. If anybody has any alternative methods for this task (Windows to Windows file transfer in gitlab-ci.yaml script) then please do offer details.

Comment: is the gitlab-runner user able to scp or ssh to other server? if so maybe user still needs to be configured?

Comment: Try adding the ["-B"](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#B) option to the `scp` command to ensure that it runs non-interactively. The ["-r"](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#r) option may also be necessary to copy whole directories.